# Router/Modem needs power-cycle every time wireless user attempts to connect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem

My home network and internet configuration consists of a Motorola SB 5102 model internet modem (to get internet), which is connected to a D-Link AC1000 wireless router, that provides wireless internet to my whole household- and 2 wired desktop workstations in the office where the router and modem are located.

Our internet works fine on both wireless and wired at any given time, and on any given device- all but one exception. One of the people that I live with recently purchased a Lenovo laptop, around the same time that I upgraded to my current wireless router. Everything was fine at first, but then one day when the user of said laptop attempted, her laptop was unable to connect, and also could not tell what the problem was other than it was not caused on the end of her laptop. After some testing on why this happened, I turned off the power strip that both the modem and router were attached too. When I turned it back on, I was able to get internet to every device previously connected (A Wired Windows 7 Desktop, A Nintendo 3DS, and an iPod Touch), which all worked even when the other laptop computer couldn't. After the power cycle, however, this laptop was successfully able to connect.

After this initial connectivity problem, Every time this user attempts to connect, the connection fails and I need to cycle BOTH devices- Router as well as modem. If i only cycle the one, It doesn't work, which I find weird- This says that the problem is caused by both the router AND the modem, and I have been using the modem for a good 2 years with no problems. Releasing the connection from my router's online settings causes the problem to be resolved about 20 percent of the time, but cycling the devices works best.

It can be very irritating if I'm, say, talking with a client over skype, and I need to disconnect just so that someone else can connect as well. Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried updating firmware of your router and updating relevant firmware/drivers on the laptop?

Comment: Haven't tried on the laptop but it is running the latest update version of Windows 7 and all of its browsers are to date. The Router, to my knowledge, has the latest firmware available for it.